# DBから抽出したレコードを指定キーワード(複数)で絞り込むロジックについて

Tags: mysql

例として掲示板システムで"コメント"テーブルから新規10件を表示、
但し"NGワード"テーブル(1レコード1NGワードを保持)にあるNGワードが含まれるコメントは
除外したい、というケースを想定して下さい。

NGワードは複数あります。
このようなケースでなるべくコストの少ない検索方法を模索しているのですが
何か良い方法は無いでしょうか。

追加：可能であればNGなコメントも取得自体はしておいてNGであるという状態を持ちたいです。
となるとNGワードテーブルを結合してそのIDがNULLかどうか、という方法しか無さそうですが・・

Comment: う～ん、not likeで絞ってから、10件取り出すくらいしか考えつきませんでした。

Comment: NGワードだったらそれを含む投稿を拒否する形が多いと思うのですが、そうではなく「別テーブルに列挙された文字列で部分一致を行い、該当しないものだけをid順に10件取り出す」という条件なんですよね。

Comment: @豚吐露 exits以上に早くなる方法は無さそうですかね・・ 実装しているサービスも多そうなのですが具体的なSQLが見つかりません・・

Comment: @unarist 私の例が不適切かもですが仰るとおりです。可能であれば該当するものも持った上で「該当しない」という状態を保持したいと思っています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「なるべくコストが少ない検索方法」とのことですが、用途的にRDBMSがあまり得意としない処理のような気がします。
とりあえずこんな感じで実装して、パフォーマンスが怪しくなってきたときに全文検索エンジンの導入等を検討してみるのはどうでしょうか。

#### DATA

```
create table blogs (
  title varchar(100),
  content text
  );

create table ng_words (
  word varchar(100)
  );

insert into blogs values ('blog1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix in tantas officiis, pro.');
insert into blogs values ('blog2', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, veri scripserit adversarium in vix.');
insert into blogs values ('blog3', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad virtute sententiae neglegentur vel.');
insert into blogs values ('blog4', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad sea nisl aliquip deseruisse.');
insert into blogs values ('blog5', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo elitr aperiri tractatos id.');
insert into blogs values ('blog6', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, alienum insolens eleifend id has.');

insert into ng_words values ('vel'); -- remove blog3
insert into ng_words values ('quo'); -- remove blog5
```

#### SQL

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM   blogs b 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM   ng_words n 
                  WHERE  b.content LIKE Concat('%', n.word, '%')) 
ORDER  BY b.title 
LIMIT  3
```

#### RESULT

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお、このコードの実行結果はこちらで確認できます。

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dea4/4

### 追記

unarist さんのコメントを受けて作った、LIKEではなくPOSITIONを使うバージョンです。
POSITIONを使うと、 % のような「LIKEで特殊な意味を持つ文字」も検索できるようになります。

#### DATA

```
create table blogs (
  title varchar(100),
  content text
  );

create table ng_words (
  word varchar(100)
  );

insert into blogs values ('blog1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix in tantas officiis, pro.');
insert into blogs values ('blog2', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, veri scripserit adversarium in vix.');
insert into blogs values ('blog3', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad virtute sententiae neglegentur %vel.');
insert into blogs values ('blog4', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad sea nisl aliquip deseruisse.');
insert into blogs values ('blog5', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, %quo elitr aperiri tractatos id.');
insert into blogs values ('blog6', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, alienum insolens eleifend id has.');

insert into ng_words values ('%v'); -- remove blog3
insert into ng_words values ('quo'); -- remove blog5
```

#### SQL

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM   blogs b 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM   ng_words n 
                  WHERE  POSITION(n.word IN b.content) != 0) 
ORDER  BY b.title 
LIMIT  3
```

#### RESULT

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### コード

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0891/1

#### LIKEを使った場合のRESULT

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### LIKEの場合のコード

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0891/3

Comment: 詳細なご回答ありがとうございます。
確かによろしくないケースというか設計から考えなおした方が良いかもしれませんね。。
全文検索エンジンを良く知らないのでそちらも併せて検討したいと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: `n.word` に `%` などのワイルドカード文字が入る可能性も考慮するなら、 `position()` を使ったほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: unaristさん、コメントありがとうございます！POSITION関数、知りませんでした。回答を追記しておきました。